# how to check NSString in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I want search (to check) one `NSString` in `NSMutableArray`. but I dont know about it.

```
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Marco",@"christian",@"hon",@"John",@"fred",@"asdas", nil];
    NSString *name = @"John";
```

I want to see is there name variable in a `NSMutableArray` variable ?

Comment: [a containsObject:name];

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too localized.  The `containsObject:` function is listed as clear as daylight on the documentation page:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **containsObject:** method to check this :

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Marco",@"christian",@"hon",@"John",@"fred",@"asdas", nil];
    NSString *name = @"John";
    if ([a containsObject:name]) {
        // Your array cotains that object
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

run a loop and check .

```
-(BOOL)array:(NSArray*)array containsString:(NSString*)name
{
    for(NSString *str in array)
    {
        if([name isEqualToString:str])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

In this way array find out object that it contains.

you can also use a single line

```
 [array containsObject:name]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are also interested in the position of your element you can use

```
 - (NSUInteger)indexOfObject:(id)anObject
```

it will return NSNotFound if the object is not in the array, or the index of the object

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
if([a containsObject: name])
{
    //here your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[a containsObject:name]
This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `indexOfObject:`. Because using this way you can not only check whether it exists but also get the index if it indeed exists.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Marco",@"christian",@"hon",@"John",@"fred",@"asdas", nil];
NSString *name = @"John";
NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject:name];
if (index != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"Find name %@", name);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Name %@ not fount", name);
}
```